# Build Failed after importing ios module in Appcelerator App

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

I am creating `FBAudienceNetwork.framework` module for iOS in appcelerator then using it in mobile App but getting compilation error for app.

I have created a module in appcelerator studio, i have put the FBAudienceNetwork.framework in module inside ios/patform folder, the module built successfully.

Then i am importing that module in appcelerator project while compiling it shows an error.

I have also follow this link : https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/ios_module_64-bit_support.html

The command lists the required architectures.
`xcrun lipo -info libcom.usp.fbaudience.a`

Architectures in the fat file: `libcom.usp.fbaudience.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64`

```
Xcode Version : 10.1
Titanium SDK  : 8.0.0.GA


var facebookAudienceNetwork = require('com.usp.fbaudiancenetwork');

[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld /Users/uspapps4/Documents/workspace2/fbAudienceNetworkDemo/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/fbAudienceNetworkDemo.build/Debug-iphoneos/fbAudienceNetworkDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/fbAudienceNetworkDemo normal armv7.
```

Comment: Hi! Did you solve your problem? I have one very similar. If so, please share and help! =)